# Cannot generate java wrapper class from contract

Tags: web3j, java

currently I am trying to generate a java wrapper contract from my smart contract. The command I use is as seen below :

```
web3j truffle generate --javaTypes C:\Users\name\Documents\test\UserAccountFactory.json -o C:\Users\name\Documents\test -p file
```

However, when I run in both Windows Powershell and Command Prompt, it shows the same error as seen below :

[image]

Can anyone help me fint out why I get this problem? Thank You

Comment: What web3j version are you using? They use a new tool to generate the wrappers epirus, http://docs.web3j.io/latest/getting_started/deploy_interact_smart_contracts/.

Comment: Hi, I am using version 4.5.16. Is there any problem with that version?

Comment: Can you please retry with the latest version of the web3j-cli: https://github.com/web3j/web3j-cli/